# Is there are a command line option for preventing the compiler to convert 64 bit into 32 bit operations in C++?

Tags: command-line-arguments, 32bit-64bit, visual-c++-2013

I get generated c-code that might have 64 bit operations and datatypes. I compile it for a 32 bit CPU so the compiler emulates the 64 bit types/operations using a series of 32 bit types/operations.
Having 64 bit types is not allowed in my case.

Is there any possibility like a command line option for the compiler to warn me during the buildprocess?
In best case i see in the compiler logfile in which file and line the compiler emulated 64 bit types/operations.

Comment: The compiler does it whenever it is needed. A "warning" does not make sense in a moment like that, it is nothing but a normal compilation.

Comment: The Visual Studio compiler does it but other compiler doesnt. Before running into troubles i would like to detect the 64 bit operations/types and convert them into 32 bit types. I hoped the Visual Studio compiler can inform me when doing 64 bit emulations.

Comment: Sorry, Alex, I don't understand what you mean. A compiler transforms source language (C++) to instruction set of a target CPU (you did not mention which CPU platform you use, I assume x86). I would not call it "emulation", it just transforms your program to available instructions. Intel x86 platform does not have any 64-bit registers or instructions, so everything is compiled into 8-16-32bit instructions. Again, this is not an emulation. If you compile to Z80 CPU which is 8-bit, everything will be represented with just 8-bit instructions. Again, no emulation is involved.

Comment: Thanks Al Kepp for your explanation. I use a x86 platform and just would like to know when the Visual Studio compiler transforms the 64 bit instructions into x86 instructions. When i compile it with another compiler on an embedded target that doesnt do the transformationsteps because of runtime reasons i run into troubles. Thats why i would like to change my code after compiling it with Visual Studio by getting any information about where the tranformation happened.